# Attaching href attribute in uib-accordion-group doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, href, bootstrap-accordion

I am using angular bootstrap's directive for showing accordion in my website. How am I supposed to add a href attribute to this uib-accordion element such that on clicking that element the url changes.

Comment: Have you solved it ?

Comment: No, still not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In that way you can do it. There was a need to see what code is put into html file from uib-accordion.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
           <a  href="here put a link" target="_blank">ABCD</a>
        </h3>
     </div>
</div>
```